# Skype menu scrolling after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, skype

I upgraded from Xubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

Now always when I click the skype tray icon it opens a menu, but very tiny and with scroll areas to scroll within the menu up and down. This is quite annoying, it's very difficult to select any option in this menu.

What do I have to do to get a full shown menu without scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out there is a simple solution:

Make your toolbar position draggable, put I up to the top of your screen. The skype tray icon menu should now be full expanded. Move your toolbar back to where you want to have it. Sykpe menu is still full expanded.

[There is even a youtube video showing this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijOB07RU0Ao)